# How do I add arguments when calling a function?

Tags: python, function

I am revising a script that currently calls other scripts as subprocesses. Instead of doing that, I'm creating functions inside of the main script to perform the tasks previously performed by subprocesses.

One of the subprocesses required that variables be passed to it as you would from the command line.

Here is the code calling the subprocess:

```
 subprocess.call("python cleaner.py < ./results/Temp.csv 
 >./results/result.csv", shell=True)

 os.remove("./results/Temp.csv")
```

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
 def cleaner(): 
      #working code that cleans certain characters out of selected 
      #.csv files.

 function("./results/Temp.csv > ./results/result.csv", shell=True)
 os.remove("./resluts/Temp.csv")
```

Ideally I'd like to use the existing code from the subprocess, but I'm open to changing it if that makes solving the problem easier. Here is that code:

```
 from __future__ import print_function
 from sys import stdin

 print(next(stdin) , end='')

 for line in stdin:

     toks = [tok.replace("\'","" 
 ).replace("text:u","").replace("number:", "") for tok in 
 line.split()]

     print(' '.join(toks))
```

The script should clean the specified temp file, copy the cleaned version to a results file, then delete the temp file. Currently it works as a subprocess, but not when I try to run it as a function. I pass the variables incorrectly and it throws this error:

```
 'TypeError: cleaner() takes no arguments (1 given)'
```

Comment: `< ./results/Temp.csv  >./results/result.csv` are not arguments, they're shell piping commands. Your program/function reads and writes to stdin/stdout, and those shell directives redirect those to files. It can only work that way with a separate process, because the shell doesn't know about your python functions. You could pass the filenames as arguments and change your function to open the files itself.

Comment: Why not just import the script? You can the give it the required arguments via argparse.Namespace. This looks very messy to me and unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the arguments as part of the function.

```
def cleaner(argument1): 
      #working code that cleans certain characters out of selected 
      #.csv files.
```

Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).